# Gmail API not a valid origin

Tags: api, gmail

I'm using Gmail API Javascript, but this is problem.

`Uncaught 
{error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhos…itelist this origin for your project's client ID."}
details
:
"Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost has not been whitelisted for client ID 731803464357-pdq2kfb0qg5ahca5gvvht343u2qmbgdk.apps.googleusercontent.com    . Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
error:
"idpiframe_initialization_failed"`

This is my config with file: http://localhost/b.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Origin HTTP header before doing the HTTP request ?

`const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Origin', 'http://localhost')`